# Unable to sort a column in Excel on Macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to record a macros that sort a column from A-Z but getting run-time error 1004. I clicked on debug and the line `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21).Range("Table8[[#Headers],[Operations ticket]]").Select` is highlighted in yellow.

This is my 1st time on VBA/Macros. Thank you for the help.

```
Sub Macro21()
'
' Macro21 Macro
'

'
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21).Range("Table8[[#Headers],[Operations ticket]]").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7").ListObjects("Table8").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7").ListObjects("Table8").Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("Table8[[#All],[Operations ticket]]"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7").ListObjects("Table8").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Comment: Now, you must click [F8] to execute that line!

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ I don't even..

Answer (score 0):

When you record a macro it records your actions in relation to where the cursor is at that point. If you rerun the macro with the cursor in a different position it will attempt to carry out your actions on the cells which bear the same relationship to your current cursor position as those affected when you recorded the macro.  In this case your code refers to

```
   ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21)
```

which is a cell 21 columns to the right of your cursor position. Depending on where your cursor was, that cell may not be in the table you want.

In this case however, that line has no effect on your code and can be deleted, which should solve your problem. In general however you should always be careful about where your cursor is when you start recording.

Comment: Hi Harassed Dad,

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I deleted the line ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21) but it's still giving me the error. I tried deleting the entire line " ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21).Range("Table8[[#Headers],[Operations ticket]]").Select " but also not working.
I also recorded a new macros and was very careful with the cursor but also getting the same thing.
Please help and thank you.

Comment: Key:=ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Range("Table8[[#All],[Operations ticket]]")

should probably be 
key:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet7").Range("Table8[[#All],[Operations ticket]]")